# Moose "Can't locate object method"

Tags: perl, moose

On running a unit test I'm getting told

> Can't locate object method "encode" via package "MockEncodingMethodROT13"

where the MockEncodingMethodROT13 "package" is a mock/stub thing.

Specifically, I get this:

> $ prove Test/BFDEn> $ prove Test/BFDEncoder.pm
> Test/BFDEncoder.pm .. 1/2
>
> #   Failed test 'UseMockROT13_getData died (Can't locate object method "encode" via package "MockEncodingMethodROT13" at BFDEncoder.pm line 30.)'
>
> #   at /export/home/me/code/base/Test/Rizzo.pm line 41.
>
> #   (in Test::BFDEncoder->UseMockROT13_getData)
>
> # Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
> Test/BFDEncoder.pm .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
> Failed 1/2 subtests
> (less 1 skipped subtest: 0 okay)

The test and mock code look like this:

```
package Test::BFDEncoder;

use Test::More;
use BFDEncoder;
use EncodingMethod;
# use EncodingMethodROT13;

##########
{ package MockEncodingMethodROT13;
  use Moose;

  extends 'EncodingMethod';

  override 'encode' => sub {
      my ($self, $data) = @_;

      $data =~ tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM/;

      return $data;
  };
}
##########

sub setup : Tests(setup) {
}

sub UseMockROT13_getData : Test(2) {

    my $plaintext = BF->new( data => 'Hello World' );
    my $rot13 = MockEncodingMethodROT13->new;
    my $testee = BFDEncoder->new( decoratedData => $plaintext, encoder => $rot13 );

    is ($testee->getData(), 'Uryyb Jbeyq', caller());
    is ($plaintext->getData(), 'Hello World', caller());
}
```

And the original EncodingMethod (and EncodingMethodROT13) modules look like this:

```
package EncodingMethod;
use Moose;
use Carp;

sub encode {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;

    carp(qq["encode" really should be implemented by a subclass.]);

    return $data;
}

1;
```

and

```
package EncodingMethodROT13;
use Moose;

extends 'EncodingMethod';

override 'encode' => sub {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;

    $data =~ tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM/;

    return $data;
};
```

And it's worth noting that a unit test using the original (i.e. non-mocked) EncodingMethodROT13 works fine, despite the code for both being practically identical!

I know it's "only" a unit test, using faked code when I could easily use the original, but I'd really like to understand why it doesn't work.  Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Interestingly, I've found out that if I move the "mock" package (MockEncodingMethodROT13) out into its own file, everything works fine.  So there's something about my declaration of that package in the same file as the unit test that is causing things to go base over apex.

Comment: We're missing a few modules to run this. Your BFDEncoder and BF seem to be proprietary. Can you create an [mcve] or supply the original code for those?

Comment: I wrote up [this mcve](https://gist.github.com/simbabque/85f3400243c247db5f7f03ae37932c46) and that seems to work. What version of Moose and Perl do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the testing framework is running the tests before runtime (perhaps at CHECK time?).

But the `override` statement, and more crucially the `extends` statement, occur at runtime.

Try wrapping the package definition at the top in a `BEGIN` block.

```perl
BEGIN {
  package MockEncodingMethodROT13;
  use Moose;

  extends 'EncodingMethod';

  override 'encode' => sub {
      my ($self, $data) = @_;

      $data =~ tr/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM/;

      return $data;
  };
}
```